# Google Chrome Extension to Edit Visual force page text boxes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, salesforce, visualforce

I've developed a simple google chrome extension, that edits current page textbox values.

This is my content.js page

```js
window.addEventListener ("load", myMain, false);

function myMain (evt) 
{
 
    try
    {
        var inputs, index;
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) 
        {
          // deal with inputs[index] element.

    if(inputs[index].type=='text')
           {
  inputs[index].value='SampleValue'; 
    }    
        }
 
    }
    catch(e)
    {    
    }    
}
```

This works fine for normal HTML pages.

BUT

This does not work for Salesforce visual force pages. 
I've used 
`document.getElementById('SamplemainPage:mainForm:pageBlock1:pageBlockSection1:myId1').value='Sample Text';`

at the bottom of my visualforce page, Then it works and change the value of my text box.

But when i put same code snippet to content.js it does not work.

How it is possible? because it says think content.js as a part of current web page. So i believe it should work

Comment: how did you include you js ? could you show me?

Comment: "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "content.js", "jquery.js" ],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
 "run_at": "document_end"

Answer (score 0):

1.Please upload you js file into static resource and

[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm][1]

2. inlcude script like this

   ```
   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MyJavascriptFile}"/>
   ```

Comment: This is not related to Javascript/Salesforce, but this is related to chrome exetensions and Visual force pages.. so i don't think this will be the solution